# Convert / Cast Task<IList<MyType>> to base type

Tags: c#, async-await

```
public class Person : People
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class People
{
    [Table("PeopleTable")]
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to cast / convert `Task<IList<<People>>` to `Task<IList<Person>>` ?

The generic async method which I call to get the data, requires the class with the sqlite attributes as the class names don't always match the table names. The problem with this is, it also returns the same type. I can't quite work out how to return the other type whilst still keeping it async.

Comment: There is related saying "You can turn  cow into a ham, but not ham into a cow". If you want to be able to switch between parent and child classes, create list of parent classes and cast to child when needed, or make parent and child implement the same interface and define list of interfaces rather than classes. Also, if function argument is generic, you could make it `IList<T>` rather than `IList<MyType>`

Comment: Yeah I get that bit, but the method where I do this conversion expects a Task return type. I can't work out how to do the conversion and return it as a task. Do I just wrap it in a Task.Run and return that ? Seems kinda crude.

Comment: You really need to provide the code related to your issue, not just some random sample of inherited classes. If the issue is in incompatibility between input and output of the function, provide the simplified version of the function showing this problem, because using the unified interface instead of classes wouldn't have any issue with conversion.

Comment: If there really isn't any async work to be done you can do whatever you need in conversion e.g `var x = (whatever)y;` and `return Task.CompletedTask;` and you'll need to remove the async keywork from the method definition.  instead of wrapping it in a Task.Run.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply be able to do:

```
Person p = (Person)peopleObject;
```

You will lose everything that the People object adds on top of the Person object. Being a Task or being in a list is irrelevant to casting so I see no issue with this.

From your code snippet, I would suggest moving the Firstname and Secondname into the Person class and just using that in a List called People without any inheritance. Of course that judgement is just made of a snippet, not your intentions or code base.

Answer (score 0):

Create

```
public class People
{
    [Table("PeopleTable")]
    public int Index { get; set; }
}

public class Person : People
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Your SqlLite Class Helper

```
   class SQLiteHelper
    {
    }
    public class GenericDB<T> where T : GenericIntDTO, new()
    {
        private SQLiteAsyncConnection _sqlconnection;
        public GenericDB()
        {
            //Getting conection and Creating table  
            _sqlconnection = LibraryHelper.DBConnection;
            _sqlconnection.CreateTableAsync<T>();
        }
        public async Task<T> GetObjectById(string id)
        {
            return await _sqlconnection.Table<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id.Equals(id));
        }
        public async Task<T> GetSingleObjectQuery(string query)
        {
            var tempobject = await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync<T>(query);
            return tempobject.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        public async Task<List<T>> GetAllObjects()
        {
            var tempobjects = await _sqlconnection.Table<T>().ToListAsync();
            return tempobjects.ToList();
        }
        public async Task<List<T>> GetAllObjectQuery(string query)
        {
            var tempobjects = await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync<T>(query);
            return tempobjects.ToList();
        }
        public async Task DeleteObject(string id)
        {
            await _sqlconnection.DeleteAsync<T>(id);
        }
        public async Task DeleteAllData()
        {
            await _sqlconnection.DeleteAllAsync<T>();
        }
        public async Task AddObject(T data)
        {
            await _sqlconnection.InsertAsync(data);
        }
        public async Task UpdateObject(T data)
        {
            await _sqlconnection.UpdateAsync(data);
        }
        public async Task InsertUpdateObject(T data)
        {
            //var temp = await _sqlconnection.Table<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.id == data.id);
            if (data.Id != 0)
            {
                data.UpdatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                await _sqlconnection.UpdateAsync(data);
            }
            else
            {
                data.AddedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                data.UpdatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                await _sqlconnection.InsertAsync(data);
            }
        }
        public async Task AddAllObjects(List<T> objects)
        {
            await _sqlconnection.InsertAllAsync(objects);
        }
        public async Task DeleteAll()
        {
            await _sqlconnection.DeleteAllAsync<T>();
        }
    }
```

Now you can call it like this if you want to search without GenericDto which in your case is People

```
            GenericDB<Person> Persondto= new GenericDB<Person>();
    PersonResult= await Person.GetObjectById("Pass id here");
```

If you want to find other than any column which is not id then you can use GetObjectByQuery

```
            GenericDB<Person> Persondto= new GenericDB<Person>();
           lst = await Persondto.GetAllObjectQuery($"SELECT * FROM {nameof(Person)}");
```

Comment: Thanks, so my code is similar to what you have and when I try to use the Person type like your example above, I get sqlite complaining the table does not exist. This is expected as the table and class are named different, so I would need to use the People type so sqlite finds the correct table, which works but then I need to convert from People to Person. So far I loop over the list and convert each item and wrap this in a task so the return type is correct for the method but it doesn't feel right. I seems a little resource intensive to loop over one list just to create another.